# How can I ensure that I read my cookies only when there are multiple cookies with same name?

Tags: cookies

I have a script which creates a cookie based on some condition. Cookie Name is `lang`.

When I set this cookie, I check if its already existing or not. If it is existing, I try to update it. However I got to know that we can't update the cookie that we don't own. Can someone confirm if this is true? Because when I set cookie, I can see two cookies with the same name.

FOr a moment even if that's not possible how can I read from my cookie only? Since there are two cookies now with same name, when I try to read it gives me the cookie created by the other app. (I am using `js-cookie` module).

I am using:

`const cookieValue = Cookies.get('lang');`

and
`Cookies.set('lang','en-US');`
to set the cookies.

I see that cookie path and name are same however domains are different.